# Adding derived class objects to vector with base interface class parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract, pure-virtual

I have an abstract class (pure virtual class/interface) that we will name A.

I have a class B that derives from A and implements the pure virtual methods of A.

I have a class C with a member that is a vector of pointers to A:

```
std::vector<A*> myVector
```

and a method:

```
add(A* item).
```

In a class D that derives from C I want to add instances/objects of class B using the add method derived from class C.

I try to write it as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    C::add( (A*) new B());
}
```

I am not sure if this does what I want? If I omit the (A*) I get the error:

> Conversion to inaccessible base class "A" is not allowed

Did I successfully add B class object pointers to the vector?

Comment: Are you sure you're using public inheritance when `B` inherits from `A`? (i.e., `class B : public A`)

Comment: @unluddite: I am not and I see how that will result in that error since the base class is inherited privately. I guess this is not the way I am supposed to solve this exercise =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

> Conversion to inaccessible base class "A" is not allowed

means you're not using public inheritance when `B` derives from `A`. If you omit the `public` keyword when specifying class inheritance, the default inheritance is private (note that for a `struct` the default is public inheritance).

```
class B : /* private */ A
```

should be

```
class B : public A
```

To answer your last question:

> Did I successfully add B class object pointers to the vector?

Yes.

Comment: @unluddute: So when casting to the private base class it works as expected? So the error is more like: "since it was privately inherited we don't know your base class, but if you cast it we will let you continue?". I have a feeling doing it like this is not recommended in the first place as one could just inherit it publicly and avoid casting it wrong.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect that C-style cast makes the error go away because it devolves to a `reinterpret_cast`, which allows for all sorts of crazy things. In any case, it may result in undefined behavior so best to avoid it.

Comment: @Phataas: When you use a C-style cast like `(A*)`, you tell the compiler to just treat that memory as if an `A` object would be there. The compiler doesn't think that you can access an `A` object there (It's a `B` object and the `A` is private!). But you are the boss and so the compiler does as it's been told and treats that memory as if it would contain all the things necessary for an `A` object. And in your case that seems to actually be true and the memory address you casted really is where the privat A object lives. But it's not guaranteed to work and not recommended to do it this way.

Comment: @sth: Thanks for the answer. When you say it's not guaranteed to work I don't see how it can't from what I know about classes and inheritance. All the base class members and functions are stored first in all the derived classes memory footprint, hence a C-style base class casts will always be valid on derived classes?

Comment: @Phataas: I'm not quite sure how much of the class layout is actually guaranteed, but yes, generally it will work. When you add multiple inheritance it breaks in certain cases, but usually you don't have that. Nevertheless, usually you don't need explicit casts to base classes, and if the bases are private there is probably a reason for that... :)